# Operator overloading in Fortran with no object creation such as in friend functions (C++)

Tags: fortran, operator-overloading, friend-function

I would like to know if there is anything similar to a "friend function", from C++, in Fortran. I would like to be able to make operator overloading without creating new objects since it is too expensive. I have already tried creating objects in a module and trying to make the overloaded operator return it, but it was not successful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your understanding of what `friend` means in C++ is incorrect.  That deals with the accessibility of private class members inside the friend function - not with object creation as part of operator overloading.  Fortran's accessibility model is different - any procedure defined in the same module as a type is a "friend" and there is nothing equivalent, in accessibility terms, to a member function.

The semantics of expression evaluation in both languages requires that the source implementation of an operator create a new object to store the result of the operation.  Fancy compiler optimisation may prevent the actual creation of a temporary for a function result in some cases, but that very much depends on details.

Comment: Functions can return pointer results that reference existing objects, which can be useful for accessor procedures and the like.  Note that in many cases, the thing referenced by the pointer will still be copied as part of using the function result.  But if storage for the result of an operation already exists, then why not just use a subroutine?  Bar a few exceptions not relevant here, functions are fundamentally for use in expressions.  Using function pointer results and manually managing the storage for the result would be very difficult for handling expressions in general.

Comment: I do agree that it is hard to handle. But I cannot overload operators using subroutine (at least not that I know), and thus these temporary objects keep being created. The best way would be some way of using a subroutine for doing the operator overloading.